# Automatically scale an SVG to its parent

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to get an SVG to automatically scale down and fit **vertically** into its parent container.

The SVG is of a signature, and I want it to shrink vertically to fix into the div in question. Once this happens the width of the div will always be more than large enough to accommodate the rest of the svg.

The fiddle I have is here, and the markup is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/3v4e4/2/

Just messing with it, it looks like setting the [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ExampleViewBox) equal to "0,0,1100,100" is about right, but I can't for the life of me generalize a rule for calculating that.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 370px; height: 30px; margin: 30px;">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 1 80 c 0.11 -0.19 3.59 -7.64 6 -11 c 5.2 -7.24 11.51 -13.76 17 -21 c 1.92 -2.53 3 -5.62 5 -8 c 6.6 -7.87 14.55 -15.43 21 -23 c 0.93 -1.09 1.95 -4.23 2 -4 c 0.14 0.71 -0.63 9.58 0 14 c 0.66 4.6 2.28 9.6 4 14 c 1.22 3.11 3 6.5 5 9 c 1.79 2.23 4.59 4.25 7 6 c 1.17 0.85 2.68 1.83 4 2 c 3.55 0.44 8.37 0.86 12 0 c 7.09 -1.67 14.75 -6.24 22 -8 c 4.65 -1.13 15 -1 15 -1"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 21 52 c 0.12 -0.07 4.58 -3 7 -4 c 3.13 -1.29 6.72 -2.51 10 -3 c 3.14 -0.47 10 0 10 0"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 108 64 c -0.02 -0.75 -0.75 -28.06 -1 -43 c -0.09 -5.56 -0.26 -10.84 0 -16 c 0.07 -1.33 0.21 -3.74 1 -4 c 2.11 -0.7 7.51 -0.39 11 0 c 2.31 0.26 4.63 1.58 7 2 c 3.27 0.58 6.88 0.08 10 1 c 11.18 3.3 23.97 7.93 34 12 c 1.18 0.48 2.27 1.86 3 3 c 2.16 3.35 4.65 7.3 6 11 c 1.2 3.3 1.61 7.33 2 11 c 0.28 2.63 0.68 5.63 0 8 c -1.82 6.37 -4.98 13.73 -8 20 c -1.21 2.51 -2.98 5.17 -5 7 c -5.02 4.56 -11.2 9.21 -17 13 c -2.67 1.75 -5.93 3.14 -9 4 c -5.08 1.42 -10.52 2.26 -16 3 c -7.11 0.96 -13.85 1.58 -21 2 l -13 0"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 185 85 c 0.1 -0.26 4.17 -9.78 6 -15 c 2.97 -8.48 4.86 -16.77 8 -25 c 2.24 -5.89 5.71 -11.27 8 -17 c 1.01 -2.51 1.01 -6.02 2 -8 c 0.43 -0.86 2.4 -2.3 3 -2 c 1.31 0.65 3.69 3.81 5 6 c 3.61 6.01 7.11 12.56 10 19 c 1.4 3.13 2.26 6.59 3 10 c 0.93 4.3 0.84 8.79 2 13 c 3.16 11.44 11 34 11 34"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 247 78 c 0.04 -0.05 2 -2.16 2 -3 c 0 -1.04 -1.01 -3.46 -2 -4 c -2.03 -1.11 -6.17 -0.95 -9 -2 c -6.05 -2.24 -11.84 -5.89 -18 -8 c -6.45 -2.21 -13.17 -3.73 -20 -5 c -7.69 -1.43 -23 -3 -23 -3"/><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 280 87 c 0.04 -0.32 1.03 -11.97 2 -18 c 0.72 -4.44 2.28 -8.54 3 -13 c 1.31 -8.08 1.67 -16.57 3 -24 c 0.25 -1.37 1.71 -2.7 2 -4 c 0.32 -1.46 -0.11 -5.14 0 -5 c 0.2 0.27 2.38 6.09 3 9 c 0.33 1.54 -0.35 3.42 0 5 c 3.87 17.56 11.56 49.11 13 54 c 0.09 0.32 1.93 -1.97 2 -3 c 0.8 -11.75 -0.18 -27.39 1 -41 c 0.82 -9.44 3.67 -24.16 5 -28 c 0.21 -0.6 3.43 0.92 4 2 c 4.46 8.42 9.16 21.76 14 32 c 0.69 1.47 2.39 2.63 3 4 c 0.62 1.4 0.27 3.58 1 5 c 4.32 8.37 10.8 17.06 15 26 c 3.4 7.25 8 23 8 23"/></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scaling of an svg to work, you absolutely have to supply a `viewBox` which matches the bounding box of the contained elements. In your case that would be something like `viewBox="0 0 360 100"`.

The bounding box can be calculated via javascript, but as I have read the `getBBox()` method is buggy in some cases. I can't comment further on that, but in this case and on chrome it works, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3v4e4/7/

Note that both `getBBox()` and `setAttribute()` are native methods and for setting the viewBox you absolutely have to use these. Using the jquery ´.attr()` method will not work as the SVG DOM is different from the HTML DOM which jquery is designed for: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom

Comment: Ahh - I see what you did.  Thanks!  so is getBBox native?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Yeah, I noticed that about setAttribute.  Any idea why IE8 gives me `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getBBox'` ?

Comment: @AdamRackis that would be because IE8 doesn't support SVG. What are you using as a fallback?

Comment: @Duopixel - not sure why I was convinced IE8 supported SVG.  But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a modern browser, you might be able to just use your SVG as the src for an IMG and set the height to 100%.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kj7Wh/

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 370px; height: 30px; margin: 30px;">
    <img src="http://openclipart.org/people/StefanvonHalenbach/StefanvonHalenbach_Battle_axe_medieval.svg" height="100%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

might not work everywhere, but the zoom command on the svg element

```
svg{zoom:32%;}
```

or, you can save the this as an svg file and edit this inside illustrator